# sort array on number in word

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an empty array

```
$stack = array();
```

Now I want to fill it with values which are in variables I `posted` from another file in a `form`

```
$aV = $_POST['aValue'];
$aP = $_POST['aPercent'];

$bV = $_POST['bValue'];
$bP = $_POST['bPercent'];

$cV = $_POST['cValue'];
$cP = $_POST['cPercent'];

$dV = $_POST['dValue'];
$dP = $_POST['dPercent'];
```

after I got the values I want to `put` them in the `stack` array.
and at the end I want to `call` the array names / values

```
 $stack[0].'<br />'.$stack[1].'<br />'.$stack[2].'<br />'.$stack[3];
```

the problem is I cant fiure out how I put them in the array correctly
I tried it like this

```
$stackA = array();
$stackB = array();
$stackC = array();
$stackD = array();


$stackA[$aP] = $aV;
$stackB[$bP] = $bV;
$stackC[$cP] = $cV;
$stackD[$dP] = $dV;

$arr3 = $stackA + $stackB + $stackC + $stackD;
```

but the problem with this is that it replaces the key (for example `$arr3= 'blue' => 24` will become `[0] => 24` I need to get `[0] => [blue] => 24` so when I call `$arr3[0]` it will say `blue 24` and when `[1] => [red] = 20` I want the first one (`[0]` to be the lowest number, in this case `[red]`) I tried using `sort()` function. But it sorts on `name` and not on the `number`

Comment: shouldn't `$aV = $_POST['aPercent'];` be `$aV = $_POST['aValue'];` ? and so on with `$bP`,`$bV` etc...??

Comment: Oh yea stupid. But that doesn't affect the code. Its just a stupid typo

Comment: Do you know how to fix the issue @PeterDarmis  ?

Comment: the value is given by $dV for example, the name??

Comment: Try changing `$stackA[$aP] = $aV;` to `$stackA = array($aP => $aV);` and so on for others

Comment: @jitendrapurohit yes that is the correct approach but still the $dP is the percentage is this the `name` of the `names`/`values` array in this question?

Comment: $dP = `name` and $dV = `number` I switced it around for some reason. Just a typo. Doesn't affect the code

Comment: Please, update the question with all the typo correction and sample values for variables, so that it gets a little clear to understand

Comment: @jitendrapurohit `Undefined offset: 0` when I try to call `echo $arr3[0];`

Comment: updated @jitendrapurohit

Comment: Do `$arr3[] = array($aP => $aV);`, `$arr3[] = array($bP => $bV);` and so on for others, remove the $stackA addition stuffs

Comment: @jitendrapurohit
And then how do I sort the array and get the elements from 0 to 3 ([0]/[1] etc) in sorted mode. For example [0] => blue => 24 , [1] => red => 20 sort the array so red is at the start and then call $arr3[0] which should be red ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//Put values in a stack with number as keys
$stack[$aV] = $aP; and so on for others.

//Sort based on keys.(eg: 24, 20 in your case)
$stack = ksort($stack, SORT_NUMERIC);

// iterate and push all of them into $arr3 in the format you need.
foreach($stack as $V => $P) {
  $arr3[] = array($V => $P);
}

print_r($arr3);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thought it was self explanable, updated with some comments to be understood more clearly.